# Can I give vehicles its real names? (e.g. Skoda, Tatra)

Tags: legal, copyright

I'm working on a simulator of old USSR transport.

But my boss is telling me that I can't put real names on vehicles, but don't get me any proofs of it. I know that you can't put real human names and company emblems, but I didn't find any info on transport names. I often see real-life naming in other simulators, but they come often as mods (exception is Subtransit).

Any thoughts on it, is he right or wrong (I don't intend to use logos of the transport)?

Comment: In doubt, either hire a lawyer, or avoid using potentially copyrighted names from the start, that'll save you work, headaches and stress.

Comment: FWIW, these are officially trademarked: [Škoda](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4809:vggvwz.2.2) and [TATRA](http://tmsearch.uspto.gov/bin/showfield?f=doc&state=4809:vggvwz.3.14).

Comment: Maybe you'll find some soviet manufacturer whose trademark has ran out (outside of the US this happens fairly quickly).

Also: There is not much difference between a company emblem and their name (for your legal purpose)